# Date Value varies in iOS and Mac after using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting some date value from server in this format **04/24/13 22:00:00**

Then I am using the date formatter and printing,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setLenient:YES];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateValue];
NSLog(@"dateString %@",dateFromString);
```

I am getting **0013-04-24 16:06:32 +0000**

I am using the same in the Mac but I am getting different result **2013-04-24 16:30:00 +0000**. I am running both on same machine.

Before iOS7 it is fine but in iOS 7 getting problem.

Why am I getting different results?

Comment: Check the `twoDigitStartDate` for the formatter on the systems where you see different results?

Comment: Actually i see difference in iOS6 and iOS7 for iOS7 i am getting "0013-04-24 16:06:32 +0000" and for iOS6 i am getting "2013-04-24 16:30:00 +0000" if u see both in iOS7 year is showing as 0013, and time also varies

Comment: So check the `twoDigitStartDate` on iOS 6 and iOS 7

Comment: How to check it, it seems twoDigitStartDate is for mac, If am wrong can you please tell how to check it.

Comment: It's there on iOS (I just checked). I see no difference between iOS 7 and 6 (both on simulator) so it's probably something else.

Answer (score 0):

The format string may be different depending upon the version of OSX and iOS.
Official data formatting guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW4